# How to automatic enter Mac Administrator's name & password when Execute a shell Script？

Tags: ios, macos, shell

I write a shell script in order to automatic packing iOS project to an ipa, some code like that:

```
#clean project
xcodebuild -target $appName clean
#build project
xcodebuild -target $appName -configuration Distribution -sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="$signProfile"
#Generate ipa 
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${diskDir}/${buildDir}/${appName}.app" -o "${ipaPath}/${appName}.ipa"
```

Lucky, it's work! But every time i run this shell need enter OS Administrator's name & password, like this 
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Wdm.png)

I think maybe the CodeSign need Administrator's authority. But I want when run this script No need to enter the username & password anymore by modifing the shell or with the help of other tool! So, is there some solution to solve this problem?

By the way, my mac version is OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, Thanks Advance!!!

Comment: Just a guess really, but maybe try `echo PASSWORD | sudo -S xcrun ...`

Comment: I tried, still need enter username & password but thank you anyway :)

Comment: Maybe `echo PASSWORD | sudo -S -u USERNAME xcrun ...` ?

Comment: Does't work!  ╮(╯▽╰)╭